# I have PHP code I need to use—how do I install it?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, php-extension

I'm trying to get some code set up to use an particular company's API.

I have experience with Perl and if I need a module installed, I type `cpan ModuleName` and most of the time it Just Works. How does that work with PHP code of similar complexity?

The company in question have a github repository with PHP Client system to access their API, which looks much the same as a perl Module.

I can git clone it, I can download it, but then what? Do I have to *install* it? There are no installation instructions. Or do I just start using it? There's a `composer.json` file in there. Do I need to run a `composer` command so it can figure out and install its dependencies like a CPAN module would? Will it install into system folders or just right there in whatever directory it happens to be in? I feel like there ought be some kind of official installation process because there's a `/tests/` folder in the files I downloaded.

Their example code literally starts like this:

```
<?php

    /* @var $CompanyName \CompanyName_Api */
    $CompanyName = new \CompanyName_Api();
    /* do interesting stuff */
```

and that's it. Of course nothing works if I just do that because it doesn't know where the CompanyName_Api files are. It works if I add this:

```
<?php
    include('/full/path/to/downloaded/files/CompanyName/src/Api.php');
```

is that all I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

In order to install all dependencies defined in `composer.json` you would run the following command inside the project directory:

```
composer install
```

This will find and download the dependencies into the `vendor` directory and it will also generate an optimized `autoloader`.

To autoload your own source files you'll need to add it to the [`autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) section in the composer.json file:

Comment: `composer install` didn't work, but `php composer.phar install` worked. What about my other question? Do I simply have to include the PHP file which matches the classname, i.e. if their code says I need to create a new `\CompanyName_Api ` I just drill down into the files they gave me and hope to find the right Api.php file? It hasn't installed that file in some common directory?

Comment: Can you supply the path to the git repo you're trying to install?

Comment: I'd rather not, because I'm going to be working with them soon. I guess I'll just use their ticketing system/phone support and get help that way.

Comment: Have you tried to add your source to the autoload section? In that case you should only have to require the needed files in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First your need to install an PHP environment like PHP, Apache and all stuff, then you need to clone that file from the git repository or just download it, then navigate to the dir and fire the command `composer install`.  It will install all of the dependencies required for that package. After that, run the code from the browser -- the package api code may have the `auto loader` file which you need to include in your current package and autoloader will do all the stuff for you. Add your folder structure and file structure so that you get a better answer on this.

Comment: I already have a working PHP and Apache. There's no autoload file, although there's an autoload entry in the `composer.json`. As for "Add your folder structure and file structure so that you get a better answer on this", that's kind of my question. Where should I put it? With a Perl module I just write `use ModuleName` and the system knows where to look. With this PHP code, I just include certain files? In which case, why don't they have that line in the documentation?

Comment: Then the documentation is not proper you need to ask module dev's for that. You can not use certain module like in perl instead, you have to tell PHP where to look, or if you know the starting point of your module you can use include_path configuration, so that php will look into those configured folders only.